# How can I encode four 16 bit uints into a 64 bit uint, and decode them again?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I wrote this function with the help of [this page on bit twiddling](http://sol.gfxile.net/boolean.html):

```
uint16_t *decode(uint64_t instr) {
  // decode instr (this is new to me lol)
  uint16_t icode = (instr >> 48) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
  uint16_t p1    = (instr >> 32) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
  uint16_t p2    = (instr >> 16) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
  uint16_t p3    = (instr >> 00) & ((1 << 16) - 1);

  return (uint16_t[]){icode, p1, p2, p3};
}
```

I have this to test it:

```
uint16_t *arr = decode(number);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

However, this prints 0 four times whatever `number` is. I also haven't solved the first part of the question, how to encode the four uint16_t's in the first place.

Comment: You cannot return an array as a pointer like that. If you really want to return an array pointer, the array has to be allocated dynamically with malloc.

Comment: Try taking the array as a function argument and filling it within the function, rather than returning it.

Comment: Cool thanks, is the rest of the function correct?

Comment: You could also return a struct containing an array of size 4; and use that.

Comment: Also, be careful. Here your "00" is harmless, but something like "020" will not be interpreted as 20 decimal, but 20 octal.

Comment: @Reinderien I just like it when my operations line up :D but thanks for that

Comment: Passing the array as argument fixed it printing only 0 btw, but I still don't know how to encode four uint16_t's.

Comment: To encode, cast each to `uint64_t` and left shift appropriately, and bitwise-or the results together.

Comment: `1 << 16` invokes undefined behaviour on platforms with 16 bit `int`.

Comment: @RastaJedi: 1) GNU is not gcc. 2) It is about C 3) Before stating such nonsense (what is "bothering" with 8 or 16 bit platforms?), you should have a look at the list of supported systems for gcc & binutils. 4) There is a differeence between the host/compilation system and the target system. gcc is often used as cross-compiler.

Comment: Whoops totally forgot I was looking at a GNU guide and not GCC. Sorry :). It's because I was reading both at the same time. I was real tired when I wrote that lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to encode the four uint16_t's in the first place

This isn't hard. All you have to do is to load each `uint16_t` to a `uint64_t` one-by-one, and then return that `uint64_t`:

```
uint64_t encode(uint16_t uints[]) {
    uint64_t master = 0;
    for (uint8_t index = 0; index <= 3; ++index) {
        master <<= 16; // Shift master left by 16 bits to create space for the next uint16
        master |= uints[index]; // Load uints[index] to the lower 16 bits of master
    } // Do this four times
    return master;
}
```

To load the `uint16_t`s in reverse order, simply replace `uint8_t index = 0; index <= 3; ++index` with `uint8_t index = 3; index >= 0; --index`.

Comment: **Really important question about this:** Is it `index++` or `++index`? I once heard that post(inc|dec)rement operators (inc|dec)rement a copy of the number they're working on, rather than the actual number.

Comment: In this case there is no difference (when used as a separate statement they work in a same way). Also in that case there is no difference even in performance. Any decent modern compiler should be able to generate same (fast) assembly for both of them in the most simple cases where there is no difference between them.

Comment: This is great, but isn't it `uint16_t uints[]` instead of `uint16_t[] uints`?

Comment: @dorukayhan the question of whether to use post vs pre is because post returns a copy that is often not used, and it takes an extra step to do this, so some people (myself) believe unless you need post or need the returned result, just use pre. But +HolyBlackCat is right about almost every system, but I still like to follow that rule (sometimes I'm not on normal systems!) (and I'm sort of OCD about my code).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is actually to use `memcpy`. Most modern compilers will optimize this into the necessary bit shifts and such for you.

```
uint64_t pack(const uint16_t arr[static 4]) {
    uint64_t res;
    memcpy(&res, arr, 8);
    return res;
}

void unpack(uint64_t v, uint16_t arr[static 4]) {
    memcpy(arr, &v, 8);
}
```

Note that the result is endian-dependent, appropriate for packing and unpacking on the same machine. Note too that I'm using the `static` array specifier to check that the caller passes at least 4 elements (when such checking is possible); if that gives your compiler grief, just remove the `static` specifier.

Comment: I don't have access to a compiler right now.. I'll test both answers tomorrow, they both look like they work right now

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't pass an array back from a function the way you currently have it (which is why you're getting 0's), you'll need to pass it via pointer or static reference.

However, since you're dealing with 2 known bit-widths, you can use a mask and shift off that:

```
out[0] = val & 0x000000000000FFFF; // 1st word
out[1] = (val & 0x00000000FFFF0000) >> 16; // 2nd word
out[2] = (val & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32; // 3rd word
out[3] = (val & 0xFFFF000000000000) >> 48; // 4th word
```

You could put this in a function or macro:

```
#define MACRO_DECODE(val, arr) arr[0]= val & 0x000000000000FFFF; \
                      arr[1] = (val & 0x00000000FFFF0000) >> 16; \
                      arr[2] = (val & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32; \
                      arr[3] = (val & 0xFFFF000000000000) >> 48;

void decode(uint64_t val, uint16_t *out)
{
    out[0] = val & 0x000000000000FFFF;
    out[1] = (val & 0x00000000FFFF0000) >> 16;
    out[2] = (val & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32;
    out[3] = (val & 0xFFFF000000000000) >> 48;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    uint16_t arr[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0} ;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%#06x = %d\n", arr[i], arr[i]);
    }

    // as a function
    decode(0xAAAABBBBCCCCDDDD, arr);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%#06x = %d\n", arr[i], arr[i]);
    }

    // as a macro
    MACRO_DECODE(0xDDDDCCCCBBBBAAAA, arr);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%#06x = %d\n", arr[i], arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you could use [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    uint16_t arr[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0} ;
    uint64_t src = 0xAAAABBBBCCCCDDDD;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%#06x = %d\n", arr[i], arr[i]);
    }

    // memcpy
    memcpy(arr, &src, sizeof(arr));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%#06x = %d\n", arr[i], arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that can help.